# Insufficient Permission [403] error while modifying the Message Label using gmail API in c#

Tags: c#, gmail-api

I am trying to read the gmail mail message, using gmail api, and after reading the mail, I am removing the message label, so that I don't need to process it again. I am able to read the mail successfully, but when I am trying to modify the message Label
(`service.Users.Messages.Modify(mods, userId, messageId).Execute();`)

then I am getting the error message:

> An error occurred: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>       Insufficient Permission [403]
>       Errors [
>               Message[Insufficient Permission] Location[ - ]    Reason[insufficientPermis
>       sions] Domain[global]>
>       ].

I am not able to figure out, what may have gone wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need either `https://mail.google.com/` or
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify` in your scopes to be able to modify messages. Do you have that?

Comment: I dint get you. Can you please elaborate

Comment: Sure! Show all of your relevant c#-code :) Hard to tell what can be wrong from just the error message.

Comment: I got the root cause. I have made the scope of  permission to GmailReadOnly. It should have the access level as GmailModify

Answer (score 5):

you need to add the priviliges to the scope variable and 
then to delete the file storedCredentials (C:\Users\Administrateur.credentials..
)

Comment: It helped me with my problem. Did not know the scope is saved in the credentials file. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with a console application using a Service Account API key. After adding all the necessary Scopes, as mentioned by [Tholle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3617886/tholle) above, the application has to be updated with the necessary permissions in the Google admin console. To do this, make sure you go to Admin console and remove the current app and execute the program again to get a new token with new permissions with the updated scope.

Another way to accomplish the same is to do what [Mohamed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5268384/mohamed-karim-sfayhi) has mentioned above. That is to remove the JSON file from the "...User\[UserName]\.credetials\[apiCredentialName].json" folder. This will force the app to authenticate and get a new token. Hope this helps some one :-)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing the Scopes variable. I assume you started with the QuickStart template which allows ReadOnly access only. You can change the scope as below:

```
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GmailQuickstart
{
    class Program
    {
        // CHANGE YOUR SCOPE HERE AND DELETE YOUR CREDENTIALS.JSON FILE IN THE PROJECT.
        static string[] Scopes = { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly, GmailService.Scope.GmailModify };
        static string ApplicationName = "Gmail API .NET Quickstart";
```

Reminder: After you changed the scope and delete your credentials.json, please re-authenticate your access from the gmail api again.

Hope it works out for you!